# Syncing node_modules in docker container with host machine

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, node-modules

I would like to dockerize my react application and I have one question on doing so. I would like to install node_modules on the containter then have them synced to the host, so that I can run the npm commands on the container not the host machine. I achieved this, but the node_modules folder that is synced to my computer is empty, but is filled in the container. This is an issue since I am getting not installed warnings in the IDE, because the node_modules folder in the host machine is empty.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.15
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install && \
    mkdir -p node_modules/.cache && \
    chmod -R 777 node_modules/.cache
COPY ./ ./ 
CMD npm run start
```

I would appreciate any tips and/or help.

Comment: Why do you think node_modules should be synchronized?

Comment: Because otherwise I keep getting errors in IDE when writing new code about missing modules. Is there a different route I should take for development with docker containers?

Comment: try npm install on host

Comment: But that would defeat the purpose of the thing which I want. I don't want to run any commands (other than docker) on the host.

Comment: host and docker are two different machines that are not related to each other in any way, if you don't want to run a lot of commands, you can write a bash script

Comment: Yes, but I would run npm install [package-name] sometimes and with current docker setup it installs it on the container, but only node_modules folder is synced back to the host machine folder without the modules in it.

Comment: The Docker file you have is well suited for packaging your application, so it's ready for deployment. It's not well suited for development.

Comment: @Ditto did you eventually found a solution for this? For example the bash script mentioned in one of the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "share" node_modules like this because there certain OS-specific steps which happen during installation. Some modules have compilation steps which need to target the host machine. Other modules have `bin` declarations which are symlinked, and symlinks cannot be "mounted" or shared between a host and container. Even different versions of node cannot share node_modules without rebuilding.

If you are wanting to develop within docker, you have two options:

1. [Editing inside a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) with VSCode (maybe other editors do this too?). I've tried this before and it's not very fun and is kind of tedious - it doesn't quite work the way you want.
2. Edit files on your host machine which are mounted inside docker. Nodemon/webpack/etc will see the changes and rebuild accordingly.

I recommend #2 - I've seen it used at many companies and is a very "standard" way to do development. This does require that you do an npm install on the host machine - don't get bogged down by trying to avoid an extra npm install.

If you want to make installs and builds faster, your best bet is to mount your npm cache directory into your docker container. You will need to find the npm cache location on both your host and your docker container by running `npm get cache` in both places. You can do this on your docker container by doing:

```
docker run --rm -it <your_image> npm get cache
```

You would mount the cache folder like you would any other volume. You can run a separate install in both docker and on your host machine - the files will only be downloaded once, and all compilations and symlinking will happen correctly.